# Windows 7 failed on my Lenovo x220 laptop; how can I upgrade the BIOS now?

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

My Windows 7 x220 Lenovo laptop stopped working today. When I searched online for the error message, I saw that Lenovo is referring to a recent BIOS update. The problem is that the laptop doesn't boot due to the issue, so how can I upgrade the BIOS?

Where can I obtain a recovery bootable USB to install this BIOS update?

Comment: Not sure about the Lenovo x220 specifically, but many BIOSes (UEFI, these days) have built-in support for upgrading from a firmware image on a USB memory stick, no operating system at all needed. It's usually a fairly well hidden advanced option (and for good reason), but it should be there. Might be worth looking into. If you do attempt a BIOS upgrade, make sure that you have both a well-charged battery as well as mains power, to reduce the risk of the upgrade being interrupted half-way through because of a power supply failure. Botched BIOS upgrades are *not fun* and may brick your computer.

Comment: The X220 firmware cannot self-upgrade. @OP: Could you please share the error message? I find it rather hard to believe that a firmware issue would suddenly cause Windows to stop working.

Comment: Sure, The error message is 2100: Detection error on HDD0. I tried different hard disk, I keep getting this error.